# Error adding button element to react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add a button to my react native code and keep getting the dreaded `element type is invalid; expect a string or a class/function but got undefined`

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Alert, Text, View, ScrollView, Button } from 'react-native';

function onButtonPress() {
  Alert.alert('hello');
}
export default function AboutTab() {
  return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <Button
          onPress={onButtonPress}
          title="Learn More"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
        />
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>

  );
}
```

My view renders just fine if I just have the text element. As soon as I add the button I get the error. I have tried switching the imports (`import Button from 'react-native'`) and changing from a class to a function. There's got to be something simple I am missing.

Comment: What version of React Native are you using? `Button` component only available in RN `>=0.37.0`

Comment: @max23_ that may be the problem I am on 0.36.1. I am in the process of upgrading now. Thanks!